# How to figure out which NodeJS core modules a package is using?

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules, polyfills

Let's say we have a package on NPM like [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got).

I want to figure out which [core NodeJS modules](https://flaviocopes.com/node-core-modules/) this package is using as I want to polyfill it on environments (like React native, or the browser).

Is there any way where I can just get a list of which core NodeJS modules this package is using without manually searching through the source code?

I know there are ways to figure out the dependency tree -- that is not what I am asking. I specificially want to know which **core** NodeJS modules are being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this that is not manual unfortunately.

However, it is pretty simple to do.

Simply search all the files in your project via your IDE. `CMD+F` for things like `crypto`, `buffer`, `stream`, etc.

https://flaviocopes.com/node-core-modules/ is a list of all the core node modules